# Project structure Maven-Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am relatively new in programming in Intellij with Java using Maven. I have one doubt how I have to start the project in order to have a structure like this (photo attached), in which the ROOT is the main module (without the src and test folder) and the one i called A and B sub-module (with parent ROOT) as Spring Boot apps?
[image: Project structure needed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ROOT pom would then be a parent pom, with packaging set to `pom`

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Then, you would need to add the ROOT module as the parent in each of the children:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>your.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>ROOT.artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

If you want to build each of the child projects when building root you would also need to include them as modules in the ROOT pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>child-module-1</module>
    <module>child-module-2</module>
</modules>
```

That being said, if you are developing Spring Boot applications, I wouldn't recommend a multi-module setup with a common parent-pom, as it would quickly become a common dependency for all your apps. Then if you want to upgrade Spring or Java version on one, you would have to do all.

Through the Spring parent pom, or Spring dependencies bom you have nice assistance with regards to dependency management and upgrading dependencies, so having one repo for each application without a common parent pom (besides the standard spring boot one) would be my preferred way to go.

Comment: In Intellij there is an archetype or setting that does this automatically?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, but if you right-click the folder of your root pom you can select add and then module to create a child module. Might do some magic, but would still look through the code manually.